# getElementById returns an object instead of an element

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have an input with an id of `name`:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
```

When I run `document.getElementById("name")` in the console, I get the element itself (`<input type="text" id="name">`), but as soon as I assign it to a variable (`var name = document.getElementById("name");`), I get the string `"[object HTMLInputElement]"`.

Why does that happen? Why can't I just get the selected input element, instead of the input element object?

Thanks.

Comment: That's how console logs a DOM element. You get `"[object HTMLInputElement]"` if you convert the object to a string. `alert` does this. Use `console.log` for debugging.

Comment: *"but as soon as I assign it to a variable (var name = document.getElementById("name");), I get the string "[object HTMLInputElement]"."* No, it doesn't. It will do that if you do something to convert it to a string. It won't if you don't.

Comment: *"Why can't I just get the selected input element, instead of the input element object?"* Elements **are** objects.

Comment: If your goal is to get the *value* of the input, that would be `var name = document.getElementById("name").value;` (note the `.value`).

Comment: if I use `.value` I'll get an empty string. I know that elements are objects, I just don't get it why I get `"[object HTMLInputElement]"` instead of `<input type="text" id="name">`. if I do the same thing with e.g. <h2>, i receive `<h2>some text</h2>` in a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use without

```
var name = document.getElementById("name")
```

or any other variable than name,

```
var myvar = document.getElementById("name")
```

you'll get

```
<input type="text" id="name">
```

`name` is property of some DOM elements.

[have a look up here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name)

Comment: thanks a lot, that solved the issue! should be careful with variable names..